how to extract data fiscal year wise in talend dynamically
I need to extract data fiscal year wise, which are the components I need to use and the expression in the component to extract data fiscal year wise?
I have used tflowiterate but am getting year wise but not as fiscal year wise

You have to add more informations (what you already tried to do, image of your job, the input data type like json, csv, database, ...)

... and how are you defining a fiscal year, as opposed to a calendar year?

Our fiscal year starts from March and ends in april. We have a coloums like order ID, Product, Invoice Date, Product ASN and others. I want to extract these data into fiscal year wise into separate files. I have used tflowiterate but it ended up giving in months. Please assist

I assume you mean starts in April and ends in March? If the month is 1-3 then just subtract 1 from the year. Or create a fiscal calendar table and join to that
